# Radio button in a group is making form submit button unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this radio button group in a form:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>

    ....

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.radio_button :status, "open", { :checked => true } %>
        <%= f.label :status, "Open" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :status, "closed" %>
        <%= f.label :status, "Closed" %>
    </div><br />

    ....

<% end %>
```

There is no Javascript code error, but the form submit button works only if either I remove one of the radio buttons from the group or disable Javascript on the browser or I delete ALL the Javascript files in the project directory. The following is the only JQuery code that makes any conditional changes to the radio buttons:

```
....

$('#hide_question_form').click( function(e) {
  $('.new_question_form').slideUp(500);
  $('#question_title').val(null);
  $('#question_description').val(null);
  $('input:radio[name="question[status]"]')[0].checked = true;
  $('input:radio[name="question[status]"]')[1].checked = false;
});

....
```

I tried commenting/deleting all Javascript files one by one to see where the problem is, but unless I delete ALL of them, the button does not works. Any specific suggestions? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Resulting HTML, as requested:

```
<div class="field">
        <input checked="checked" id="question_status_open" name="question[status]" required="required" type="radio" value="open" />
        <label for="question_status">Open</label>
        <input id="question_status_closed" name="question[status]" required="required" type="radio" value="closed" />
        <label for="question_status">Closed</label>
</div><br />
```

Comment: Maybe the one you deleted last was the problem. Also, which one do you remove to make it work again?

Comment: could it be possible to see the resulting html? (i never used ror and will never try)

Comment: @Asad Any one of them, does not matters which one.

Answer (score 0):

am i wrong or do you have multiple of theese divs?

if so the problem would be that you have multiples of the same id in your resulting html.

html id's are required to be unique in order to run javascript at all. document.getElementById as example only returns one element and not multiple.

the id's i refer to are: question_status_open and question_status_closed

Comment: Yes, so aren't they unique IDs? Besides, I do have multiple of these divs and they were working just fine before. (In fact, that's how Rails scaffolding generates them too.) I don't know when this stopped working and as I said I have tried to single out specific codes, but it did not work. I have to delete all JS codes for the button to work.

Comment: are the id's the same in other divs? this looks like a template you use in multiple places on your page.

Comment: No, these radio buttons (with their unique IDs) are only in this div.

Comment: have you tried using the developer console of your browser to see if there are javascript errors or if there are files not getting loaded?

Comment: if there would not be an error the form would submit. it could be that that error would first show up when you try to submit it. all i can do is guess since i cannot try it myself.